# In material design, why dialog actions should be in all-caps?

Tags: material-design, dialog

According to Google's material design guidelines, a typical dialog with two actions looks like this:

[image]

The title and the text is normal, but what I find interesting is using all-caps letters for the actions.

In the guidelines, it doesn't address this point directly. But, in the case of languages without letter capitalization, it says:

> For languages without capitalization (such as Chinese, Japanese or Korean), it is important to maintain consistent placement, spacing, and colors for actions to distinguish them from regular text.

So I assume the main reason is for *distinction from regular text.*

But as users in the above languages (my own language as well) have no problem recognizing the actions, I was wondering **why it should be capitalized in English and similar languages**?

And, what other reasons can be behind this guideline?

Comment: It wouldnt be a suprise if this guideline came as a result of an a/b testing.

Comment: Adding one point to this, will it be a good practice to give same emphasis(here by using same color) to both the buttons i.e. DISAGREE and AGREE ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have the reason: **to raise distinction**.

- Make distinction with non-caps text
- Raise importance visually on the UI
- Raise importance when the user taps

These are the options:

[image]

All of them are understood. However, in the all caps example the order of importance goes

*Title->Actions->Description*

(or even the actions before the title), while in the others this order is not as evident at first glance.